# Character Divergence using Kullback Divergence

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I am trying to calculate the divergence of character within a string but I really don't know how to apply the Kullback Divergence algorithm to a problem like this. Please can anyone explain the KLD algorithms that I can possibly use to tackle a problem like this.

Thanks

Comment: how can i use scipy to get the generator of a probability distribution with min KL divergence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KL divergence is a metric that can give you something of a pseudo-distance between one distribution and another assuming they have similar domains (as in they assign probabilities to similar things.. bernoulli distribution gives probabilities to 0,1 coin flips, normal gives to real numbers, etc).

KL(distribution A, distribution B) is sort of a measure of how surprised I will be to be getting stuff sampled from A when I was expecting stuff sampled from B.

Its not really a distance metric because its not symmetric i.e. if, for a domain of [1,2,3,4,5], distribution A gives equal probability to all numbers but distribution B gives all probability to only 2, then KL(B, A) should be much lower than KL(A, B) because I will be a little surprised to see my uniform distribution always return the same number but I will be flabbergasted to see my only-2 distribution return something from [1,3,4,5] because those were deemed impossible by distribution B (probability 0).

Its not immediately clear to me how you are trying to use KL divergence to measure differences between strings. Please elaborate your question so that I can help you with figuring this out.

Wikipedia Article about KL - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence

Comment: thanks for the answer . I am trying to do the probability of characters in string compared to English alphabet  e.g string AAAAKAA and distribution of [a-z] which gives 1/26 each. I hope I am clear enough

Comment: ok, so you are treating that string as a distribution {'A': 7/8, 'K': 1/8, everything else: 0}, and then you are trying to compare that to a uniform distribution over the alphabet.. cool, so your domain consists of the 26 letters of the alphabet and each of these 2 distributions assigns every letter of the alphabet with a probability.. just use the equation from the wikipedia article to calculate KL (every iteration of that Sigma operator is for a different letter of the alphabet).. whats the problem with that?

Comment: I don't really see where you are going this.. I am not sure what qualitative aspect of the word will this metric be measuring :S .. fwiw googling for "entropy of a string" might give you pages with people who have similar goals to what you have. (I have heard of people trying to measure the entropy of string on SO before, but haven't read those posts properly to see what they were trying to do)

Comment: also your string is in upper case, but you explain your uniform distribution in terms of [a-z], you can either lowercase everything or give each letter 1/(26 * 2) probability instead